# Keras Model Misinterprets Input Data Shape

Tags: python, tensorflow, keras

I have a generator, which `yield`s the following:

`yield {'ingredients': ingredients, 'documents': documents}, labels`

The yield'd iterator has the following shape:

`ingredients.shape (10, 46) documents.shape (10, 46) labels.shape (10,)`

Once this iterator is fed through do my model, I get the following:

`ValueError: Error when checking input: expected ingredients to have shape (1,) but got array with shape (46,)`

Here is the model code which produces the above error:

```
    # Both inputs are 1-dimensional
    ingredients = Input(
        name='ingredients',
        shape=[1]
    )
    # ingredients.shape (?, 1) 
    documents = Input(
        name='documents',
        shape=[1]
    )
    # documents.shape (?, 1)

    logger.info('ingredients %s documents shape %s', ingredients.shape, documents.shape)

    ingredients_embedding = Embedding(name='ingredients_embedding',
                                      input_dim=training_size,
                                      output_dim=embedded_document_size)(ingredients) 

    # Embedding the document (shape will be (None, 1, embedding_size))
    document_embedding = Embedding(name='documents_embedding',
                                   input_dim=training_size,
                                   output_dim=embedded_document_size)(documents)
```

Answer (score 1):

The `input_shape` mentioned in the `ingredients` and `documents` Input layer is ( 1 ). But, the shape of ingredients is ( 10 , 46 ) and that of the documents is ( 10 , 46 ). Here 10 is the number of samples.

You are initializing the model to have an input of shape ( None , 1 ). It should be ( None , 46 ). Hence, you can make these changes.

```
ingredients = Input( name='ingredients', shape=( 46 , ) ) 
documents = Input( name='documents', shape=( 46 , )
```

This should fix the error. Actually speaking the input has 46 dimensions or 46 features.

Comment: Yes, good thought.  I had the same lol.  That shifts the error to: `ValueError: total size of new array must be unchanged`

Comment: The line is question is `merged = Reshape(target_shape=(46,))(merged)`